# How to use external html file as template in a component of Angular9?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, templates, frameworks

I am working on a Angular9 application, I have searched all over internet but couldn't find any answer on how to use external html file as template in one of the components. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? it's not possible since the template is processed compile-time (på the IVY compiler).

If you want to acquire a template at compile time, I'd create scripting to acquire said template, and replace an existing "dummy" template. This scripting needs to run prior to running the ivy compiler (eg. `ng build`).

The correct (and possible) way of doing it, is to acquire data from an external endpoint, and then present this through a compoennt. That is the way SPAs work.

Remember, data can be anything, it can be hard data, but also meta-data (such as colors, layout etc.)